Error when I try to play music from a YouTube link
So I tried to make my own discord.py bot with the function to play music from Youtube. Everytime I run  it tho, the bot does join the voice channel, but it gives an error and doesn't play anything:
Command 'playy' raised an exception: OSError: ERROR: Unable to extract uploader id; please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; see  https://yt-dl.org/update  on how to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.
This is my code:
@tree.command(name = "playy", description = "Frančesko začne hrát vybranou hudbu!y")
async def test(interaction: discord.Interaction, id: str):

        search = "morpheus tutorials discord bot python"
        channel_id = int(id)
        voice_channel = client.get_channel(channel_id)
        g = await voice_channel.connect()

        search = search.replace(" ", "+")
        html = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + search)
        video_ids = re.findall(r"watch\?v=(\S{11})", html.read().decode())
        song = pafy.new(video_ids[0])
        audio = song.getbestaudio()
        source = FFmpegPCMAudio(audio.url, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
        g.play(source)

Anyone has an idea how to fix this? I have tried almost everything and still nothing.
I also found that the original youtube-dl website doesn't exist/work.
I tried reinstalling, adding it to the system variable paths, etc. (Just everything on StackOverflow)

This thread may help: Discord.py - Streaming Youtube Live into Voice

Also there's a complete walkthrough on how to make high quality music bot  playlist
